# Implementing a user registry in a c++ based server

Tags: c++, database

So I'm planning to develop a Community feature for a game I'm developing. Currently, the high score server, which I want to integrate this user registry with is developed in pure c++.

Is there a c++ library for developing user registries? Currently, I am thinking of implementing the user registry by saving to the file system, but if there are libraries for this it'd be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a very open ended question.

If you intend to have quite a lot of users and possibly do reporting on data or have to manage pieces of data manually.... you may want to look into sqlite.  There would be slightly less administration and overhead than using a fully featured DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want the high score server in C++? Seems a bit out of place for me.

I would suggest something higher like PHP or Python with a SQLite database. Undoubtly example scripts for user registration can be found on the internet.